# How to make Matlab creating matrixs faster during the iteration?

Tags: matlab, matrix, parallel-processing

I need to create a square matrix $V$ iteratively over 100000+ times per pack.
When just doing it traditionally, the computational consumption is at around 70s.(Over 1 mintes) And I need to repeate this process for over 100 packs.That's about 1 hours extra time.

It turned out to me that when calculating the matrix using a double for loop $V(x,y)$, the matlab is only using a single thread. Howver, there are 12 threads in the computer, and there should be a way to use all of them to assign the matrix faster.

The type of function is 
$V(x,y)=exp((x-variation_1).^2+(y-variation_2).^2)$

I thought about using GPU. However, as it turned out, the GPU array is calculating it much slower than CPU.

I also thought about using the parpool function. However, not only it cost more time to send the matrix into the parallel pool, is also denied the access to the $V$ itself.

How can I tell the CPU to calculating the matrix with all the threads at faster speed?

Comment: please include an example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  It is very hard to understand what you are doing

Comment: Please add your loop code.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use matrix and vector operations rather than for loop.
If `x` and `y` are constant for all cases, you can use [meshgrid](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate `x` and `y` once.

for example, consider the following code which uses double for loop:

```
v = zeros(10000,10000);
tic;
for x=1:10000
    for y = 1:10000
        v(x,y) = exp((x/10000).^2+(y/10000).^2);
    end
end
toc
```

On my computer it runs about 11 seconds.
Now by using `meshgrid`:

```
%This is done only once
[x,y] = meshgrid((1:10000)/10000,(1:10000)/10000);

tic;
v = exp(x.^2+y.^2);
toc
```

Which takes about 4 seconds, not including the `meshgrid`.